# Error on PHP Site when Copying/Paste from Outlook into Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, outlook, textarea, richtext

Some of our users are experiencing a problem after copying and pasting text from MS Outlook into a text area box on our PHP site (running in IE, seems to work fine in other browsers). Specifically, the contents are apparently pasted properly, but when the data is passed back to the server and stored in the PostgreSQL database, no data is actually stored in the database (I'm about to check to see if the PHP is even receiving it in the `$_POST` variable, I'll post an update when I've done that).

It sounds like a problem with rich-text formatting or perhaps the encoding of what is pasted.

**Does anyone know of a solution that we can apply to the PHP site to enforce that the text area only accept plain text (or automatically convert it) for IE?**

Thanks!

**Update:** Sadly, I cannot reproduce the bug on IE 6, 7 or 8 using Outlook Express. Perhaps this is user error...I'll  update with more info when I figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: Rich text formatting? That doesn't sound like a normal textarea. Can you add more detail? and examples?

Comment: Could you post some code samples ?

Comment: Start by logging the actual received input. This could be a problem anywhere between sanitizing input, SQL escaping and encoding issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen when some symbols copied are high-ASCII characters, and there is a mismatch with encodings you are working with. Make sure the page, your program, and your database use the same encoding (e.g. all use UTF-8, or whatever you use). I've encountered weird problems (empty strings, cut-off at the instance, etc) with inserting data that has characters like these.

But of course, check that you're actually getting the data to your program in the fist place :)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `strip_tags` when pulling out from `$_POST`.